# Remove create and edit depending up on value of another field in odoo11

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

Need to remove create and edit in partner_id field in sales order depending on value of another field. I found one similar answer but it not working.

```
<field name="partner_id" position="replace">
   <field name="partner_id" string="partner" domain=[('customer','=',True),('sale_invoice_type','=',sale_invoice_type)]" context="{'search_default_customer':1, 'show_address': 1,'default_sale_invoice_type':sale_invoice_type}" attrs="  {'invisible': [('sale_invoice_type', '=', 'cash')]}" options='{"always_reload": True, "no_create_edit": True}'/>         

   <field name="partner_id" domain="[('customer','=',True),('sale_invoice_type','=',sale_invoice_type)]" context="{'search_default_customer':1, 'show_address': 1,'default_sale_invoice_type':sale_invoice_type}" attrs="{'invisible': [('sale_invoice_type', '=', 'credit')]}" options='{"always_reload": True}'/>

</field>
```

When the sale_invoice_type is cash edit and create should be removed

Answer (score 3):

First the domain of both field should look like this

```xml
    <field ....  attrs="  {'invisible': [('sale_invoice_type', '!=', 'cash')]}"/>

    <field ....  attrs="  {'invisible': [('sale_invoice_type', '=', 'cash')]}"/>
```

IF The solution didn't work because you should not have the same
field two time in your view Odoo will be confused witch one to pass.

But you can workaround it by creating a new field.

In your model define another partner field just a dummy one to use it instead of 
the real partner_id but make sure that both field at the end of write and create 
will always be equal.

```py
    partner_no_create = fields.Man.......
```

In your code make sure that this two field always equal:

```py
    # I think this onchage handle the cases in Odoo views
    @api.onchange('partner_id')
    def set_partner_no_create(self):
        if self.sale_invoice_type != 'cash':
            self.partner_no_create = self.partner_id


    @api.onchange('partner_no_create')
    def set_partner_no_create(self):
        if self.sale_invoice_type == 'cash':
            self.partner_id = self.partner_no_create
```

In your XML

```xml
       <field name="partner_no_create" string="partner" domain="[('customer','=',True),('sale_invoice_type','=',sale_invoice_type)]" 
           context="{'search_default_customer':1, 'show_address': 1,'default_sale_invoice_type':sale_invoice_type}" 
           attrs="  {'invisible': [('sale_invoice_type', '!=', 'cash')]}" options='{"always_reload": True, "no_create_edit": True}'/>         

       <field name="partner_id" domain="[('customer','=',True),('sale_invoice_type','=',sale_invoice_type)]" 
           context="{'search_default_customer':1, 'show_address': 1,'default_sale_invoice_type':sale_invoice_type}" 
           attrs="{'invisible': [('sale_invoice_type', '=', 'cash')]}" options='{"always_reload": True}'/>
```

But still have to handle more cases specially when the record is updated or create from RPC call, you need to 
override create and write method to handle all cases.

Comment: Thanks for help, I've already used second method you mentioned. first method is not working. Is there any other to achieve by using the same field

Comment: I don't know. I didn't find another solution